# Any XML based proxy service. Not giving UTF-8 encoding in request payload, still after processing i am getting UTF-8 encoding in my inbound variable

Tags: xml, osb, oracle-service-bus

I am new to OSB, and  using OSB11G. Can we remove UTF-8 encoding from inbound variable in our Proxy service?

Requirement is :

**Please remove** :`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

**Use** :`<?xml version="1.0"?>`

Answer (score 0):

The "encoding attribute in the XML declaration is a required field. Hence,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

is not valid. What you can do is to completely remove the declaration with something like

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ArK. Was wondering if that can be done. One more thing if you can help me with. My client system parser is not accepting <example/> instead it demands <example></example> ....

Comment: This seems to be be not a restriction of the parser, but more likely a Schema issue. From your statement I conclude that you validate the XML and that givens you an error, right? If so, this is because of the underling Schema having a definition of an element with empty content, just like: <xs:element name="example">
    <xs:complexType/>
  </xs:element>

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle Service Bus's default encoding for HTTP inbound transports is ISO-8859-1 and For HTTP outbound transports is UTF-8 and I would prefer using it unless there are reasons not to.

Having said that, there is a way you can configure a different encoding. I am assuming that you are using an XML based Proxy and using HTTP Transport. On HTTP Transport Configuration Page, you can configure both Request encoding and Response encoding.

Further details are available [in the OSB Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/admin.1111/e15867/proxy_services.htm#OSBAG1068).